# JavaScript functions to search and replace image names with img tags in a block of text

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am a noob trying to write JavaScript functions that search for image names in a block of text and replaces them asynchronously by creating an img tag by calling an HTTP GET method that returns binary blob data. Below is my code that is part of a JavaScript module. The replaceTextWithImages() function returns before the loadImage() call finishes.  I have tried using the `await` key word before loadImage(), but I get an error that says "await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules". Thanks for your help !

```
async function getImage(url) {
            'use strict';
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET', url);
                request.responseType = 'blob';
                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status === 200) {
                        resolve(request.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error('Image didn\'t load successfully; error code:' + request.statusText));
                    }
                };
                request.onerror = function () {
                    reject(new Error('There was a network error.'));
                };
                request.send();
            });
        }

        async function loadImage(name, alt, callback) {
            'use strict';
            var retStr;
            console.log("Trying loadImage...");
            getImage('/getImage/' + name).then(function (response) {
                return response.arrayBuffer();
            }).then(arrayBuffer => {
                let binary = '';
                let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                let len = bytes.byteLength;
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                var imageURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(binary);
                retStr = "<img src='" + imageURL + "'" + " alt='" + alt + "'>";
                console.log(retStr);
                callback(retStr);
            }, function (Error) {
                console.log(Error);
            });
        }

        async function replaceTextWithImages(content) {
            preprocessContent(content);
            if (ifHasImages(content)) {
                var imageArray = getArrayOfImagesFromContent(content);
                imageArray.forEach(function (imageName) {
                    var altText = getAltText(imageName);
                    var imgTag= loadImage(imageName, altText);                        
                    content = content.replace(replaceStr, imgTag);
                    console.log("updated content => " + content);
                });

            }
            console.log("content => " + content);
            return content;
        }
```

Comment: What is the code in which you call the functions and where you have use await? The error normally just means, that you have to make the function in which you use await into an async function. But we would need to see how you call the functions to make sure.

Comment: In the my code above replaceTextWithImages() calls loadImage(). When I change `var imgTag= loadImage(imageName, altText);` to `var imgTag= await loadImage(imageName, altText);` I get an error that says "await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules".

Comment: If you set `await` like that, then you have to do this:`imageArray.forEach(async function(imageName){...` to make the function, in which you use `await`, async.